# Angular Material button remove autofocus

Tags: css, button, angular-material, default

I have the following button

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="downloadStuff(element)">
    <mat-icon mat-icon matTooltip="{{element.someId}}">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>
  </button>
</td>
```

All good but I noticed the little bugger gets outlined by default:

[image]

Ok.... CSS lets me remove the annoying outline withe the following:

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

But then.. I still get this annoying default background focus:

[image]

I've tried a few overlay and background-related things in CSS and none of these seemed to address the issue. 
How do I remove this default background?
And why does it behave like this by deafault???

See the selected item in dev tools. 
[image]

Comment: This is normal behavior for Material design as you can see from [this guide](https://material.io/design/interaction/states.html#focus). Have you tried adding `background-color: none;` to your &:focus CSS ?

Comment: Thanks Jake but background-color: none;  was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: If you use Chrome's DevTool and inspect the element and set it to focus, what CSS is applied ?

Comment: Visual focus indication is an important part of usability. The solution to your problem is to remove focus, not to suppress the focus indicator because that would make for a bad user experience. It happens by default because of something you are doing or something you are using - we need to see how you are using the button to know why. Usually a simple button on a page does not get focus by default (e.g. https://xonklxyamje.angular.stackblitz.io/ code: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xonklxyamje?file=app%2Fbutton-types-example.html).

Comment: I added a copy of the selected button taken from dev tool in Chrome. 
The button is generated dynamical depending on the number of rows in the table. It is just added to one of the table's cells.

Comment: You may be able set `tabindex="-1"` on the button if you want to remove it permanently

Answer (score 37):

After clicking or touching on a Material Design button it stays focused ---> to resolve this, you need to add the following code: `onclick="this.blur()"`

```
<button mat-raised-button  onclick="this.blur()" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
```

or in your case

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <button mat-icon-button type="button" onclick="this.blur()" (click)="downloadStuff(element)">
        <mat-icon mat-icon matTooltip="{{element.someId}}">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>
    </button>
</td>
```

Comment: What's the difference between onclick and (click)?

Comment: Here it was explained bought of with examples. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: It works, but the focus is shown for some miliseconds, then blur, making an ugly effect. I prefer the solution given by Rafique Mohammed

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31):

In my case the real problem was the button structure. Angular Material builds various sub components and the last one is a 'div' with css class `mat-button-focus-overlay`:

My solution is simply. In `style.css` add or overwrite the `mat-button-focus-overlay`:

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I was able to get rid of the default focused button by setting the attribute *cdk-focus-start* on other item.
More info available [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/2879#issuecomment-276713257)

Comment: Thanks.  Sent me in the right direction for my problem.  FYI, `cdk-focus-start` deprecated, use `cdkFocusRegionstart` instead.

Answer (score 7):

In your styles css, just add this code. It will remove those annoying outline from all the buttons

```
button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I suppose there is a better solution to this, because the examples in https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview don't use this, but it works!

Answer (score 6):

Also try this.

```
<button mat-icon-button [autofocus]="false" (click)="closeDialog()">
  <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
</button>`
```

Just add `[autofocus]`.

Comment: or you may put on the <button  type="button"></button>.

Answer (score 6):

Question is somewhat old. But I found a better solution for this.

Add **tabindex="-1"** to the button tag and problem solved!

```
<button tabindex="-1" mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="downloadStuff(element)">
    <mat-icon mat-icon matTooltip="{{element.someId}}">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not a better solution. You are removing keyboard navigation of tab.

Comment: Thanks, a real solution among all these "why not fix the global styles to remove the initial focus, great idea"

Answer (score 3):

Use this to remove both outline and auto focus in your **.css**:

```
button {
  outline: none;
}

::ng-deep .mat-button-focus-overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for :focus, :cdk-keyboard-focus and so on, you can remove box-shadow

```css
box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following css code in your outermost style file.

```
.mat-focus-indicator::before {
border-color: transparent !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just add cdkFokusInitial on the submit button or something else

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following (sort of) the [Accessibility section](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focusmonitor) of Angular Material.

Here is my AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("appContainer") appContainer: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

    appContainerOrigin = this._formatOrigin(null);

    constructor(
        private _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
        private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private _ngZone: NgZone,
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this._focusMonitor.monitor(this.appContainer, true).subscribe((origin) =>
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.appContainerOrigin = this._formatOrigin(origin);
                this._cdr.markForCheck();
            }),
        );
    }

    private _formatOrigin(origin: FocusOrigin): string {
        return origin ? origin + " focused" : "blurred";
    }
}
```

Its template:

```
<div #appContainer class="app-container">
    <app-header></app-header>

    <div class="content-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

And the styles.scss file at the root of the project:

```
.cdk-mouse-focused *:focus {
    --mdc-list-list-item-focus-state-layer-color: none;
}
```

FocusMonitor adds a CSS class to the .app-container div which tells you how the focus was made. I then remove the color layer associated to the focus from the focused element if it was made by a mouse click. That way you get the same behavior as the Angular Material doc, as you can see in the [Buttons doc](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview). I don't think the Angular Material team implemented it like that, and I also don't think that's the ideal way to achieve it (a simple directive built in Angular Material by default would be nice) but it's the closest I could get from the expected behavior.